# Meteor: clicking the link from Accounts.sendResetPasswordEmail

Tags: meteor

`Accounts.forgotPassword()` triggers `Accounts.sendResetPasswordEmail()` and the email is successfully sent. But when I click on the link in the email, a new instance of my app (new browser window) is brought up.  How can I prevent that from happening?  I want to stay in the calling app, not open another instance of it.

Comment: Am I understanding correctly that you want your email program or browser to open the link in the same window/tab that the site is currently open in? I don't think this is possible to do easily (without browser extensions or similar). And it doesn't make sense to me either bc. you may well receive your mail later in the future or on a different device.

Comment: Not possible due to the way email integrates with browsers.

Comment: Makes sense.  Thanks.  Just, from the user's point of view - (s)he clicks 'forgot password' in one window and there's a reply in another.  How do developers generally deal with this issue?